# firebase command is not working . it always shows Pkg: Error reading from file

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I've tried to install firebase tools on my macOS several times . I used npm , the auto install script and standalone binary, but nothing have worked .

When I write on my terminal commands like `firebase login` it shows me

> "Pkg: Error reading from file."

None of the firebase commands work . Even if I tried commands like `firebase help` or `firebase -v`, the terminal always show me the same error.